# DotNet ForecastBySsa does not predict simple series

Tags: c#, forecasting, ml.net

I found this dotnet interface for time series forecasting Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TimeSeries and followed the official example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/time-series-demand-forecasting
This forecast is about car rentals but to make sure I understand the algorithm, I want to solve a super simple problem. So I took the number series 1, 2, 3, ..., 998, 999, 1000 and taught it on that and tried to evaluate it on the number series 15, 16, ..., 23, 24. However I get completely wrong results, so I must be doing something wrong.
Basically it predicts after 15 should be -144 and after 16 is -143. Clearly I'm messing something up, can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
        public void TimeSeries()
        {
            string rootDir = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "../../../"));
            string modelPath = Path.Combine(rootDir, "MLModel.zip");
            List<TestInputData> training = new List<TestInputData>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
                training.Add(new TestInputData(i));
            List<TestInputData> evaluation = new List<TestInputData>();
            for (int i = 15; i <= 24; i++)
                evaluation.Add(new TestInputData(i));
    
            MLContext mLContext = new MLContext();
            IDataView trainingData = mLContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<TestInputData>(training);
            IDataView evalData = mLContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<TestInputData>(evaluation);
    
            var forecastingPipeline = mLContext.Forecasting.ForecastBySsa(
                outputColumnName: "result", inputColumnName: "input", windowSize: 10, seriesLength: 100, trainSize: training.Count,
                horizon: 10, confidenceLevel: 0.95f, confidenceLowerBoundColumn: "confidenceLowerBound", confidenceUpperBoundColumn: "confidenceUpperBound");
    
            SsaForecastingTransformer forecaster = forecastingPipeline.Fit(trainingData);
    
            Evaluate(evalData, forecaster, mLContext);
    
            var forecastEngine = forecaster.CreateTimeSeriesEngine<TestInputData, TestResultData>(mLContext);
            forecastEngine.CheckPoint(mLContext, modelPath);
    
            Forecast(evalData, 10, forecastEngine, mLContext);
        }
    
        void Forecast(IDataView testData, int horizon, TimeSeriesPredictionEngine<TestInputData, TestResultData> forecaster, MLContext mlContext)
        {
            TestResultData forecast = forecaster.Predict();
    
            IEnumerable<string> forecastOutput =
                mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<TestInputData>(testData, reuseRowObject: false)
                    .Take(horizon)
                    .Select((TestInputData inputData, int index) =>
                    {
                        float actualInput = inputData.input;
                        float lowerEstimate = Math.Max(0, forecast.confidenceLowerBound[index]);
                        float estimate = forecast.result[index];
                        float upperEstimate = forecast.confidenceUpperBound[index];
                        return $"Actual input: {actualInput}\n" +
                        $"Lower Estimate: {lowerEstimate}\n" +
                        $"Forecast: {estimate}\n" +
                        $"Upper Estimate: {upperEstimate}\n";
                    });
    
            // Output predictions
            Console.WriteLine("Forecast");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
            foreach (var prediction in forecastOutput)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prediction);
            }
        }
    
        private void Evaluate(IDataView testData, ITransformer model, MLContext mlContext)
        {
            IDataView predictions = model.Transform(testData);
    
            IEnumerable<float> actual = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<TestInputData>(testData, true).Select(observed => observed.input);
    
            IEnumerable<float> forecast = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<TestResultData>(predictions, true).Select(prediction => prediction.result[0]);
    
            var metrics = actual.Zip(forecast, (actualValue, forecastValue) => actualValue - forecastValue);
    
            var MAE = metrics.Average(error => Math.Abs(error)); // Mean Absolute Error
            var RMSE = Math.Sqrt(metrics.Average(error => Math.Pow(error, 2))); // Root Mean Squared Error
    
            Console.WriteLine("Evaluation Metrics");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"Mean Absolute Error: {MAE:F3}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Root Mean Squared Error: {RMSE:F3}\n");
        }
```

The input and result data classes are just data holders:

```
    internal class TestInputData
    {
        public float input;
    
        public TestInputData(float input)
        {
            this.input = input;
        }
        public TestInputData()
        {
        }
    }
    
    internal class TestResultData
    {
        public float[] result;
        public float[] confidenceLowerBound;
        public float[] confidenceUpperBound;
    }
```

Output:

```
Evaluation metrics:

Mean Absolute Error: 360,218
Root Mean Squared Error: 23,250

Forecast:
Actual input: 15
Lower Estimate: 0
Forecast: -144,46222
Upper Estimate: -144,46117

Actual input: 16
Lower Estimate: 0
Forecast: -143,16403
Upper Estimate: -143,16295

Actual input: 17
Lower Estimate: 0
Forecast: -140,90327
Upper Estimate: -140,90215

Actual input: 18
Lower Estimate: 0
Forecast: -141,51913
Upper Estimate: -141,51793

Actual input: 19
Lower Estimate: 0
Forecast: -148,5618
Upper Estimate: -148,5605

Actual input: 20
Lower Estimate: 0
Forecast: -164,48706
Upper Estimate: -164,48566

Actual input: 21
Lower Estimate: 0
Forecast: -188,74472
Upper Estimate: -188,7432
```

I tried increasing the training data to 1.000.000 with worse results, I tried changing the window size, series length and horizon but without any luck.. but I'm not an expert on what these values should be.
I also tried looking for similar questions but those I found only mentioned how values are expected to be off, I didn't find any showing a truly simple example that is obvious to everyone like this.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the random results is that your windowSize(10) is larger than your evaluation data series length (9).

running your code and just increasing the length of the evaluation series to 100, gives this output:

```
    Evaluation Metrics
---------------------
Mean Absolute Error: 44.531
Root Mean Squared Error: 11.980

Forecast
---------------------
Actual input: 15
Lower Estimate: 101.000404
Forecast: 101.00145
Upper Estimate: 101.002495

Actual input: 16
Lower Estimate: 102.00102
Forecast: 102.002106
Upper Estimate: 102.00319

Actual input: 17
Lower Estimate: 103.00223
Forecast: 103.003365
Upper Estimate: 103.0045

Actual input: 18
Lower Estimate: 104.00367
Forecast: 104.004875
Upper Estimate: 104.00608

Actual input: 19
Lower Estimate: 105.00469
Forecast: 105.00599
Upper Estimate: 105.007286

Actual input: 20
Lower Estimate: 106.00481
Forecast: 106.00621
Upper Estimate: 106.007614

Actual input: 21
Lower Estimate: 107.00453
Forecast: 107.00606
Upper Estimate: 107.00758

Actual input: 22
Lower Estimate: 108.00475
Forecast: 108.00641
Upper Estimate: 108.008064

Actual input: 23
Lower Estimate: 109.00608
Forecast: 109.00786
Upper Estimate: 109.009636

Actual input: 24
Lower Estimate: 110.00677
Forecast: 110.0087
Upper Estimate: 110.01063
```

Notice the predictions start at 101, despite the input value being 15. Then they go up by 1 with each input increment.

I suspect the reason for this is that this time series analysis is looking forward. i.e., you give it a series that has happened, and it predicts what will be the next value. You have trained the model on a series that just increments linearly (y = x + 1), and it succeeded in learning that. Then when giving it a series to predict the next value for, it correctly predicts it as the last value of the series + 1.

It's probably designed to be used on series that are cyclical, e.g., temperature that changes with season.